# Problem connecting two nodes in Flowchart

Tags: tikz-pgf

:)

I am trying to create a very simple flowchart with `tikzpicture` but I am having trouble with it.

My code:

```
% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=4.5em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm,
    minimum height=2em]

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
    % Place nodes
    \node [block] (init) {Begin};
    \node [decision, below of=init] (hasSession) {Has SessionID?};
    \node [block,left of=hasSession, node distance=5cm] (pSession) {Persist Session};
    \node [block,below of=hasSession, node distance=5cm] (pVisit) {Persist Page Visit};
    \node [block,below of=pVisit] (end) {End};
    % Draw edges
    \path [line] (init) -- (hasSession);
    \path [line] (hasSession) -| node [near start] {no} (pSession);
    \path [line] (pVisit) -- (end);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This makes me the following chart

[image: flowchart obtained]

The is an obvious issue, which is the arrow on "Persist Session". Besides, if I add the following line:

```
\path [line] (pSession) -- (pVisit);
```

It gives me the error of dividing by zero.

Any clue, on both issues and further tips since I will need to enhance the flowchart with more nodes and edges?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `-|` instead of `--`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,positioning,arrows}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{decision/.style={diamond, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=4.5em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt},
block/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em},
line/.style={draw, -latex'},
cloud/.style={draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm,
    minimum height=2em}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
    % Place nodes
    \node [block] (init) {Begin};
    \node [decision, below of=init] (hasSession) {Has SessionID?};
    \node [block,left of=hasSession, node distance=5cm] (pSession) {Persist Session};
    \node [block,below of=hasSession, node distance=5cm] (pVisit) {Persist Page Visit};
    \node [block,below of=pVisit] (end) {End};
    % Draw edges
    \path [line] (init) -- (hasSession);
    \path [line] (hasSession) -- node [near start] {no} (pSession);
    \path [line] (hasSession) -- node [near start] {yes} (pVisit);
    \path [line] (pVisit) -- (end);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]